# Missing Tabbar when segue from over current context

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to press a button on ViewController 1 which moves me to ViewController 2(over the current context of ViewController 1). Afterwards i want to press a button on ViewController 2 and move me to ViewController 3 without losing the tabbar

ViewController 1(with Tabbar) ---> ViewController 2(over current context of ViewController 1) ----> ViewController 3(with Tabbar)

Problems:

1: Segue with push does not work with cross dissolve animation

2: Segue with Detail works great visually and with animation but i lose Tabbar

Is it possible to use (over current context with cross dissolve animation) and not lose Tabbar ? A problem which i have been attempting to solve for 2 weeks. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Can you try this line: self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = false

Comment: Not sure how this will solve anything. Do you want me to use this line on the second ViewController after i (segue with detail) from ViewController 1?

Comment: You said you lose your tab bar when you go to your 3rd vc, try to set it to true from vc1 to vc2 and false from vc2 to vc3. Can you put some more code or are you using the segues from storyboard?

Comment: That is correct. I lose the Tabbar when i use (segue with detail). The code line didn't do any difference unfortunately. I am using storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

try to embed ViewControllers into UINavigation

Comment: I have tried that. Without any results unfortunately.